# Seed generates a completely different world on the same version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Minecraft world that I was playing on with my friend in January 2021. The world was originally created on 1.16.4 on a Minecraft server. There were no mods nor plugins that were changing the world generation, it was a pure normal minecraft world. The state of the world right now is pretty... uhh... covered with things, and I wanted to see how the world looked like in the beginning.

The problem is that the seed from the world generates a completely different world than the original world that I have. The world was updated thrice from 1.16.4 to 1.16.5, then from 1.16.5 to 1.17.1, and then from 1.17.1 to 1.18.2. I installed one mod to the server once, that just made the Ender Dragon drop more loot, but other than that it didn't change anything.

The interesting thing is that I also have a second world that I made with my friend too, it was a whole separate world though with different terrain and things. I typed the `/seed` command on that world too on the version that it was created on, and it gave me the SAME seed that the first world gave me, but the seed also doesn't create the world that is the same as the second world.

I know this is confusing, but to sum it up: both worlds create the same seed that doesn't generate any of these two worlds on the same versions they were created in.

Does anyone perhaps know why that happens and how to fix it?

Comment: perhaps the /seed command in those worlds is returning the wrong seed? What kind of server are you running (vanilla, paper, forge, something else)?

Comment: I was running the server on Aternos on Bukkit, but i typed the /seed command on a singleplayer by downloading the world. The server also gave me the same seed that i got in singleplayer

Comment: Did your new world upgrade to a new version?

Comment: Well as i said, i updated the world thrice to the new versions, from 1.16.4 to 1.16.5, then from 1.16.5 to 1.17.5 and then from 1.17.2 to 1.18.2. The second world though wasn't updated at all and it was created on version 1.16.5.